# akka-http 'Directive0' to force the inner route be evaluated separately for each request?

Tags: akka-http

Within akka-http, routes are evaluated only once (at build time), unless they rely on some dynamic, extracted parameter (client IP, request header, anything).

One of my custom directives depends on a side effect (a potentially changing system file), so I wish to execute it separately, each time. I'm looking for an `extractNothing` that I could wrap it with.

Is there such?

Ability to consume a parameter would also work, then I can `(extract[Unit](_) & consume)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routes Are Still Dynamic**

You are correct that routes are evaluated only once.  However, the body of any Route can be dynamic in nature.

As an example, suppose we have a function that returns the current time:

```
val getTime = () => System.currentTimeMillis().toString
```

This function can be embedded within a `Route`:

```
val route = 
  get {
    path("currentTime") {
      complete(getTime())
    }
  }
```

**Updating File Route**

Now each HttpRequest will get a different time value back even though the `route` is a `val`.

Similarly, you could use [streaming file io](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io) in akka to create a dynamic `HttpResponse`, the entity of which is the contents of your changing file:

```
val fileResponse = () => {
  val file = Paths get "sourceFile.txt"

  val chunkSource = FileIO fromPath file 

  val chunkEntity = 
    Chunked.fromData(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, chunkSource)


  HttpResponse(entity = chunkEntity)
}

val fileRoute = 
  get {
    path("sourceFile") {
      complete(fileResponse())
    }
  }
```

**Inner & Outer Routes**

Extending the example 1 step further to dynamic Routes, you could write a function that fails every other time:

```
val halfBaked = () => {
  var isGood = true

  () => {
    if(isGood) {
      isGood = false 
      complete(fileResponse())
    }
    else {
      isGood = true
      complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
    }
  }
}
```

And wrap this in an outer Route :

```
val innerRoute = halfBaked()

val outerRoute = 
  get {
    path("feelingLucky") {
      innerRoute()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice answer. However, in my case it's the directive itself that needs to be re-evaluated. It's fetching an authentication client id from the disk, and those may be rotated. So your approach unfortunately does not work.

Comment: @akauppi Updated my answer based on comment.  Also, your question somewhat suggests a design flaw.  You should isolate side effects & state to the lowest level, smallest space, possible.  In my example case the isGood state resides within a utility function.  It sounds like you have side effects all the way up to the Route level.

Comment: You are so right about the design flaw! Because of your answer, I revisited the thinking and was able to move the file-depending behaviour into a route, instead of being inside a directive. Much cleaner, me very pleased! :)